# clear-icon not working in combo box in vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I have created a combo box with chips using vuetify and made it deletable. I wanted to change the remove icon of the chip in the combo box, I tried using **clear-icon** to change them, but it is not working. I read in the documentation that the icon is *applied when using clearable and the input is dirty* . So I added clearable, even that didn't work. Please help!

Here is my code :

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout wrap>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-combobox
            v-model="select"
            outline
            multiple
            deletable-chips
            chips
            clearable
            clear-icon="clear"
          ></v-combobox>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here is the demo link : https://codepen.io/KousikaGanesh/pen/KbaNzX

Comment: `clear-icon` prop is not used for changing remove-chip icon, but that icon on the far right (besides, `clear` is the default icon). I guess you'll need to use slots.

Comment: yes you are correct @Traxo! Thanks! I used slot and it worked!

Comment: Could you explain how did you solved this issue?